# What is the "scope" of a CKServerChangeToken?

Tags: ios, cloudkit

As described in https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckserverchangetoken, the CloudKit servers return a change token as part of the  CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation callback response. For what set of subsequent record fetches should I include the given change token in my fetch calls?

- only fetches to the zone we fetched from?
- or would it apply to any fetches to the db that that zone is in? or perhaps the whole container that the db is in?
- what about app extensions? (App extensions have the same iCloud user as the main app, but have a different "user" as returned by fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:, at least in my testing) Would it be appropriate to supply a change token from the main app in a fetch call from, say, a Messages app extension? I assume not, but would love to have a documented official answer.

Answer (score 7):

I, too, found the scope of `CKServerChangeToken` a little unclear. However, after reviewing the documentation, both `CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation` and `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation` **provide and manage their own server change tokens.**

This is particularly useful if you decide to follow the CloudKit workflow Dave Browning outlines in his [2017 WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/226/) when fetching changes (around the 8 minute mark).

The recommended approach is to:

1) Fetch changes for a database using `CKFetchDatabaseChangesOperation`. Upon receiving the updated token via `changeTokenUpdatedBlock`, persist this locally. This token is 'scoped' to either the private or shared `CKDatabase` the operation was added to. The public database doesn't offer change tokens.

2) If you receive zone IDs via the `recordZoneWithIDChangedBlock` in the previous operation, this indicates there are zones which have changes you can fetch with `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation`. This operation takes in it's own unique server change token via it's rather cumbersome initializer parameter: `CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation.ZoneConfiguration`. This is 'scoped' to this particular `CKRecordZone`. So, again, when receiving an updated token via `recordZoneChangeTokensUpdatedBlock`, it needs persisting locally (perhaps with a key which relates to it's `CKRecordZone.ID`).

The benefit here is that it probably minimises the number of network calls. Fetching database changes first prevents making calls for each record zone if the database doesn't report any changed zone ids.

Here's a [code sample](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords/MaintainingaLocalCacheofCloudKitRecords.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014987-CH12-SW7) from the CloudKit team which runs through this workflow. Admittedly a few of the APIs have since changed and the comments don't explicitly make it clear the 'scope' of the server change tokens.